# How to make that query?

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

Let's imagine we have table tasks contains

```
user_id  date   
1         2015-01-01      
1         2015-01-01     
1         2015-01-02        
2         2015-01-03
```

How to display data like below

```
user_id      count       date
   1          2           2015-01-01
   1          1           2015-01-02
   1          0           2015-01-03

   2          0           2015-01-01
   2          0           2015-01-02
   2          1           2015-01-03
```

Comment: It seems like you'd want a table containing all the unique users if the zero counts are important. Do you have that?

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY, which may in time prove problematic

Answer (score 2):

If the zeros *are* important, then you might do something like this:

```
select
    user_id_date_crossjoin.user_id,
    user_id_date_crossjoin.`date`,
    coalesce(`count`, 0) as `count`
from
    (select
      user_id,
      `date`
    from
      (select distinct user_id from tasks) all_userids,
      (select distinct `date` from tasks) all_userid_dates
    ) user_id_date_crossjoin
left outer join
    (select
       user_id,
       count(*) as `count`,
       `date`
    from tasks
    group by user_id, `date`) user_id_date_counts
on user_id_date_crossjoin.user_id = user_id_date_counts.user_id
and user_id_date_crossjoin.`date` = user_id_date_counts.`date`
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e17090/3

Comment: Glad to hear it. :) If you don't get a more awesome solution, will you please accept it as an answer?

Comment: i'm thinking to do it in application layer that query might be slow with large data

Comment: That makes sense, @OmarMakled. I wish I'd have answered "do it in the application layer". That would've nailed it. C'est la vie.